# Post event build exit with code 1 error in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

Here is the script:

```
copy /y "$(SolutionDir)Libs\Detect.dll" "$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
call editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE SER.EXE > post.txt
call dumpbin.exe /HEADERS SER.EXE > post1.txt
```

The error is

> Error 306 The command "copy /y "C:\dev\blah\Libs\Detect.dll" 
>   "C:\dev\blah\Debug" call editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE SER.EXE >
>   post.txt call dumpbin.exe /HEADERS SER.EXE > post1.txt" exited with
>   code 1.

Comment: If `SER.EXE` only appears in Release folder, you can manually edit the project file to add a condition to the post build event, so that it only works for release build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Post event build exit with code 1 error in Visual studio 2013

Only one thing needs to be confirmed: Is this `SER.EXE`executed only in the release mode or just this `SER.EXE` is exist in the release folder and should be executed in the debug and release mode?

**If this `SER.EXE`only need to be executed in the release**, Lex`s suggestion should to be considered. Pre- and Post-Build Events run as a batch script. You can do a conditional statement on $(ConfigurationName). For example:

```
copy /y "$(SolutionDir)Libs\Detect.dll" "$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release call editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "SER.EXE"> post.txt
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release call dumpbin.exe /HEADERS SER.EXE > post1.txt
```

**If this `SER.EXE` is exist in the release folder and should be executed in the debug and release mode**, you just need to specify the release folder in the command:

```
 call editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "Release\SER.EXE"> post.txt
 call dumpbin.exe /HEADERS "Release\SER.EXE"> post1.txt
```

Obviously, you also need make sure the `SER.EXE`can be executed, you can use below command to test in the console application project:

```
call editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "$(TargetPath)"> post.txt
```

**Note:** When you want use this post-build event in both debug and release mode, you should add the command line for all configuration, Otherwise this command will only act on one mode (Just a reminder):

[image]

Hope this help.